# how can i download AppCompatActivity librery for ADT

Tags: java, android, adt

I have a problem with importing the package :
    "import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity".. i think because i should 
    download AppCompatActivity librery before importing it

```
Please, how can i download AppCompatActivity librery??

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMPQs.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Setup Android Support Library :**

The Android Support Repository package is provided as a supplemental download to the Android SDK and is available through the Android SDK Manager.

Follow the instructions below to obtain the Support Library files.

**To download the Support Library through the SDK Manager:**

1.Start the Android SDK Manager.

2.In the SDK Manager window, scroll to the end of the Packages list, find the Extras folder and, if necessary, expand to show its contents.

3.Select the Android Support Repository item.

4.Click the Install packages... button.

Then After Downloading,

**Adding Support Libraries**

In order to use a Support Library, you must modify your application's project's classpath dependencies within your development environment. You must perform this procedure for each Support Library you want to use.

**To add a Support Library to your application project:**

Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using the SDK Manager.
Open the build.gradle file for your application.
Add the support library to the dependencies section. For example, to add the v4 core-utils library, add the following lines:

```
dependencies {
...
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1"
}
```

Then you can use your Support Library elements.

Answer (score 1):

No need to download it separately.You can fix it updating your "build.gradle(Module:app)" file. in order to do it you need to add your compiler dependencies for project.

Add this line to "build.gradle(Module:app)" file

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
```

then Sync your project and make sure network connection is working.That's it :)

bellow is an example that shows where you add a compiler dependency to your project.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espressocore:2.2.2',{
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```